# Why does right shift (>>) bit operation over byte give strange result?

Tags: java, math, bit, bitwise-operators

There is a byte `[01100111]` and I've to break it in such way `[0|11|00111]`
so after moving parts of this byte into different bytes I'll get:

```
[00000000] => 0 (in decimal)
[00000011] => 3 (in decimal)
[00000111] => 7 (in decimal)
```

I've try to do that with such code:

```
byte b=(byte)0x67;
byte b1=(byte)(first>>7);
byte b2=(byte)((byte)(first<<1)>>6);        
byte b3=(byte)((byte)(first<<3)>>3);
```

But I got:

```
b1 is 0
b2 is -1 //but I need 3....
b3 is 7
```

Where I've mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Why is there a break after the first Zero, but not after the second group of zeros? [0|11|00|111] or [011|00111]. And what is `first`? Is it `b`?

Comment: oops, I've mistake. first is actually b

Comment: I've break in such way according to my data format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your results are being automatically [sign-extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

Try masking and shifting instead of double-shifting, i.e.:

```
byte b1=(byte)(first>>7) & 0x01;
byte b2=(byte)(first>>5) & 0x03;
byte b3=(byte)(first>>0) & 0x1F;
```

Comment: So how can I do them unsigned?

Comment: @stemm Also look at the `>>>` operator (different than `>>` in how it treats sign-extension). Although, I recommend the shift and mask as well (it's less thinking ;-) +1 Oli.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. And one more generally: if I need unsigned byte as result of operation a>>x I need to mask it with hexadecimal mask, in which way I have to calculate this mask?

Comment: @stemm: Java doesn't have unsigned types.

Comment: I'm understand, that there is no unsigned types in java, but I need unsigned results.

Comment: @Oli char (16-bit) and bool (1-bit)? </pedantic>

Comment: @Stem try: `byte b2=(byte)((first<<1)>>>6);` The problem is the inside cast.